# \bm{p} in the section title or subsection title produces error?

Tags: errors, packages

When I do this it says (my file is named Test.tex):

```
./Test.tex:397: TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
<to be read again> 
                   \HyPsd@@LetCommand 
l.397 \subsection{Here the error occurs $\bm{p}$}

./Test.tex:397:  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Test.log.
```

`\mathbf{p}` and `\vec{p}` works and do not produce errors when written instead of `\bm` above.

Some minor info: **I want p bold in the title because that would represent a vector in my case**. p has a subscript that I don't want bolded.

Comment: `\protect\bm` (fragile command in moving argument)

Comment: OK thanks I'll try this. Should I write that in the preamble, or every time in the title when needed?

Comment: Or write `\subsection{Here the error occurs {\boldmath $p$}}`. But *a prior* yoy probably want all yours maths in a section title to be bold, like the text of the section title. Then write `\boldmath` at the beginning of the section title  and drop the enclosing brackets.

Comment: @Bernard I guess this is a good temp solution, although the "p" have a subscript that I do not want bolded. There must be a better way.

Comment: Actually the best, in my opinion, is to redefine the section format with the help of `titlesec`  and include `\bfseries\boldmath` in the global formatting.

Comment: In my opinion the best is to *not* making math bold. Math alphabets have a semantic value in themselves and a normal math italic `p` is different from a boldface italic `p`.

Comment: @egreg I specifically want bold italic p in the title. I understand your concern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not a fragile command in a moving argument, because `\bm` is robust. The culprit here is `hyperref`.

You have two ways for solving your problem:

1. type `\section{A vector \texorpdfstring{$\bm{p}$}{p}}`
2. add `\bm` to the list of commands to be neutralized when bookmarks are made

The second strategy is perhaps better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref,bookmark}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{#1}}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand{\vect}[1]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{A vector $\vect{p}$}

\end{document}
```

You'll have to live with the warning

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `math shift' on input line 12.
```

though.

Defining `\vect` is better than using directly `\bm`, because it adds semantics to your commands.

[image]

Comment: Hey I checked that bm wasn't robust: the first line of the package is `\def\bm#1#2{% \let\bm@pmb\install@mathalphabet` which is fragile, but I forgot to read past the first line where it is defined later with `\DeclareRobustCommand` The author saved one csname to help emtex....

Comment: I'll check it out and also consider your comment on \vect. 

Perhaps off-topic, but perhaps it is not wise to use \bm{p} for vectors in the first place? It is rarely used, and perhaps it is too much hassle to use it? I'm scratching my head right now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The author of `bm` always uses smart tricks that sometimes outsmart him.

Comment: @LoveLearning Bold italic for vectors is required by ISO, as far as I know. Of course, mathematicians do not care.

Comment: @egreg I followed your #2 and so far so good. I will also use \vect for the rest of my life from today.

Comment: @LoveLearning And if you change your mind about the typesetting of vectors, you just need to change one line instead of chasing through the document for `\bm`.

Comment: @egreg man you are so right. Thank you very much for the help. 

I had to chase through the document and change every \bm to \vect but like you say, had I done the definition from the get go I would've never have to do it now. But the document is still small so it's OK :) But it's just awesome to be able to switch in a second if needed :)